# Angular2 - Rollup Tree shaking (*.ngfactory - could not be resolved)

Tags: angular, rollup, angular2-aot, rollupjs, tree-shaking

I try to use Tree-shaking for Angular 2 app after AOT compilation, and I catch the next message:

> 'Containers/module.ngfactory' is imported by Containers\module.aot.js,
>   but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
>
> No name was provided for external module 'Containers/module.ngfactory'
>   in options.globals – guessing 'Containers_module_ngfactory'

And I don't know how to fix this.

this is **module.aot.js** code after AOT compilation:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
enableProdMode();
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ModuleNgFactory } from 'Containers/module.ngfactory';
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(ModuleNgFactory);
//# sourceMappingURL=module.aot.js.map
```

**rollup-config.js**

```
'use strict';

import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

export default {
    entry: './Containers/module.aot.js',
    dest:  './module.vendor.js',
    sourceMap: false,
    format: 'iife',
    onwarn: function(warning) {
        // Skip certain warnings
        if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) { return; }
        if ( warning.code === 'EVAL' ) { return; }
        console.warn( warning.message );
    },
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
        }),
        uglify()
    ]
}
```

and **tsconfig-aot.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "app/*": [ "../src/*" ]
        },
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "../src/globals.ts",
        "../src/Containers/module.aot.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings"
    ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": "../",
        "skipMetadataEmit": false,
        "skipTemplateCodegen": false
    }
}
```

In general, AOT works fine, but I can't run to tree-shaking for a bundle my code to the one file.

Help me please resolve this problem.

**UPD**

It's problem just with the main **module.aot.js** file.

Any suggestion how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solutions for this case. It's very simple, but I had spent for this many time :(

In the each an Angular components we need to put a correct patch to the other service, module, etc.

For example:

If we have a project structure like this:

```
|-main.ts
|-src
        | - service
                | - authorize.service.ts
        | - login
                | - login.component.ts
```

then in the **login.component.ts** you would like to **import** **authorize.service.ts** from **service** folder, you need to put a patch to this service like this:

```
import { donothing } from '../service/authorize.service'
```

It's very strange but the Angular app with **JIT** or **AOT** works well if we put next path to this service:

```
import { donothing } from 'service/authorize.service'
```

And the second case it's path to some service, module, etc, which is situated in the current directory.

For example:

We have a project like previous but in the root folder we have **helper.service.ts** file.

```
|-main.ts
|-helper.service.ts
...
```

If you try to include **helper.service.ts** in the **main.ts** like this:

```
import { donothing2 } from 'helper.service'
```

or

```
import { donothing2 } from '/helper.service'
```

It will be work with **JIT** and **AOT** but doesn't work when we a try to run **Rollup** for **tree-shaking**.

Solution very simple but for me it's strange.

We need to put `.` before a file name, because without the `.` it's treated as an external import.

```
import { donothing2 } from './helper.service'
```

I hope my answer will be helpful for someone.

Thanks.